# How to add add some msi application to visual studio InstallShield Redistributables?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, installshield

I used Visual Studio 2015 InstallShield Limited Edition Project to create my application setup.

My application must be installed api.msi, .net3.5 and .net4.5 to be exeuted.

In "Specify Application Data->Redistributables", I only can add .net3.5 and .net 4.5 to my setup. but i can't add api.msi to Redistributables.

How do i add api.msi to Redistributables?

[this is my Redistributables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OldGf.png)

I hope the installation steps are as follows

run setup->set install path->install .net(3.5 and 4.5) & api.msi & application.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it is by creating merge module and add it to your project for details refer the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6z02ts5(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield can include either merge modules or prerequisites, but the Limited and Express editions do not include the capabilities to build either. Both options are available with the Professional and higher editions, and other tools may be able to create merge modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can download an eval copy of InstallShield and throw it on a VM.  Build your setup prereq file (.PRQ) for it.  Copy the PRQ and api.msi to your machine with InstallShield LE and consume it.

You can read more about how to author a PRQ here: (Disclosure: My blog article from 11 years ago)

http://iswix.com/2006/11/21/using-installshield-12-to-install-net-framework-3-0/

I maintain an open source project called IsWiX that creates graphical UIs for managing XML documents.  I thought about creating a tool to maintain PRQ files.  It would only take me a day to write it but I was concerned Flexera might get really irritated. :)